# Compute $\int \frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{x^2+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Compute $$\int \frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{x^2+1}dx$$

**Attempt**

$u=\sin(x)\Rightarrow du=\cos(x)dx$
$$\int\frac{u}{x^2+1}du$$
But, now I have both $u$ and $x$ in the function. How do I resolve?
Second attempt:
using Maclaurin series for $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$,
$$\sin(x)=1-x^3/3!+x^5/5!...$$
$$\cos(x)=1-x^2/2!+x^4/4!...$$
$$\sin(x)\cos(x)/(x^2+1)=(1-x^3/3!+x^5/5!...)(1-x^2/2!+x^4/4!...)/(x^2+1),$$ we can simplify the numerator and divide each term by $x^2+1$, but how do we simplify the numerator?

[image]

How do we simplify this expression in order to integrate this integrand?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You need to eliminate $x$ completely when you do the substitution - leaving the denominator as $x^2+1$ after the substitution is not going to help.

Comment: Is there a reason to expect the integral to have a closed form? Most integrals do not.

Comment: WolframAlpha uses some special functions to find this, but it doesn't show up the steps.

Comment: Are you perhaps really interested in a particular definite integral of the integrand, say, over $[0, \infty)$?

Comment: No, my second attempt is to use Maclaurin series

Comment: integral(sin(x) cos(x))/(1 + x^2) dx = ((e^4 - 1) Ci(2 i - 2 x) + (e^4 - 1) Ci(2 x + 2 i) + i (1 + e^4) (Si(2 i - 2 x) + Si(2 x + 2 i)))/(8 e^2) + constant is the answer

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}&\int \frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{x^2+1}dx \stackrel{u=2x}{=}\int\frac{\sin u}{u^2+4}du=\frac1{4i}\int\frac{\sin u}{u-2i}du-\frac1{4i}\int\frac{\sin u}{u+2i}du\\
&=\frac1{4i}\int\frac{\sin(v+2i)}{v}dv-\frac1{4i}\int\frac{\sin(w-2i)}{w}dw
\\ &=\frac{\cos2i}{4i}\int\frac{\sin v}{v}dv+\frac{\sin2i}{4i}\int\frac{\cos v}v dv-\frac{\cos2i}{4i}\int\frac{\sin w}w dw+\frac{\sin2i}{4i}\int\frac{\cos w}{w}dw
\\ 
&=\frac1{8e^2} (-(e^4+1)i\operatorname{Si}(v)+(e^4-1)\operatorname{Ci}(v)\\ &\quad\;+(e^4+1)i\operatorname{Si}(w)+(e^4-1)\operatorname{Ci}(w) )+C\\
&=\frac1{8e^2} (-(e^4+1)i\operatorname{Si}(2x-2i)+(e^4-1)\operatorname{Ci}(2x-2i)\\ &\quad\;+(e^4+1)i\operatorname{Si}(2x+2i)+(e^4-1)\operatorname{Ci}(2x+2i) )+C\end{align*}
which is the same answer given by Maths lover in the comments, since $\operatorname{Si}$ is an odd, $\operatorname{Ci}$ is an even function.

Comment: Please provide reference for Ci and Si.

Comment: @Gary I don't fully have references yet. My guess is that $Si(x)=\int \sin x dx/x $ and $Ci(x)=\int \cos x dx/x$. But then I had sign mistakes. :(

Comment: Try to match them with [these](http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2.ii) definitions.

Comment: @Gary  Thsnks. I am in jail. If I escape I will update

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that this can be massaged into a nice expression, but we have;

$$\int\frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{x^2+1}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\sin(2x)}{x^2+1}dx$$

$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n4^{n}}{(2n+1)!}\int\frac{x^{2n+1}}{x^2+1}dx$$

Applying the substitution $u=x^2+1$ yields;

$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{4^{n}}{(2n+1)!}\int\frac{(1-u)^{n}}{u}du$$

By the binomial theorem we will then have;

$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{4^{n}}{(2n+1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k\cdot n!}{k!\cdot (n-k)!}\int{u^{k-1}}du$$

Our second sum will produce a divergence when $k=0$ if we simply apply the primitive of $u^{k-1}$. So we must peel the first term of our sum off and evaluate it separately;

$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{4^{n}}{(2n+1)!}\bigg(\int u^{-1}du+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k\cdot n!}{k!\cdot (n-k)!}\int{u^{k-1}}du\bigg)$$

This gives us our final giant mess;

$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{4^{n}}{(2n+1)!}\bigg(\ln(x^2+1)+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n!\cdot (-(x^2+1))^k}{k\cdot k! (n-k)!}\bigg)+C$$

Comment: $u=x^2+1$ yields "$...\frac{(u-1)^{n+1/2}}u$."